# How should I calculate the intersection of subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces, intersection-theory

How should I calculate the intersection of subspaces? In Z5.

span{(1, 4, 4), (2, 3, 4)} ∩ span{(1, 1, 4), (2, 4, 0)}

And how many vectors it includes?

Comment: To answer the second question you only need the dimension of the intersection: any $d$ dimensional vector space over a field of $k$ elements has $k^d$ elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $(x,y,z)$ is an element of the interseaction. So you can express it in two ways:

$$\alpha_1(1,4,4)+\beta_1(2,3,4)=(x,y,z)=\alpha_2(1,1,4)+\beta_2(2,4,0)$$

Thus:
$$\alpha_1(1,4,4)+\beta_1(2,3,4)-\alpha_2(1,1,4)+\beta_2(2,4,0)=0$$

Solve this system of the equations (over $\mathbb{Z}_5)$, and you will get that:
$$\alpha_1=0$$$$3\alpha_2=\beta_2$$$$\beta_1=\alpha_2$$
So vectors in the intersection are of the form:

$$(x,y,z)=\beta_1(2,3,4)$$
Check all the values of $\beta_1$ from $0$ to $4$:

$\beta_1=0:(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$

$\beta_1=1:(x,y,z)=(2,3,4)$

$\beta_1=2:(x,y,z)=(4,1,3)$

$\beta_1=3:(x,y,z)=(1,4,2)$

$\beta_1=4:(x,y,z)=(3,2,1)$

So the intersection is:

$$\{(0,0,0),(2,3,4),(4,2,3),(1,4,2),(3,2,1)\}$$

Comment: isn't the third $(4,1,3)$ instead of $(4,2,3)$

Comment: @LEO yes, my bad - I fixed it

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand it.